Why is home ownership so low in Switzerland?
According to Wiki and OECD data, only 42% of Swiss people own their home. This indicator is the lowest in Europe and the third lowest in the World. But why is this the case? Switzerland is one of the richest countries in the world and local income inequality isn't too bad by European standards. It's also one of the few countries placing any restrictions on secondary home ownership, so I'm surprised primary home ownership isn't at a higher rate.

Did you take a look at the price of real estate ? It's unaffordable for most people, I would bet that most owner inherited their home.

@BouncyChips its also very high in Canada but 66% own their home there

Don't think it's as high as in Switzerland. See https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/87123/46935

@BouncyChips OECD data disagrees, Switzerland's price-to-income ratio is better than Canada's: https://data.oecd.org/price/housing-prices.htm

Part of the reason is that for cultural and/or economic reasons that may not be attractive. The reasons like housing security or stable investment are not just weighty enough in a stable and prosperous economy. On the other hand, taking good care of a house is quite a hassle.

I disagree with the close votes. Switzerland indeed has multiple political peculiarities that directly contribute to low home ownership (high mortgage interest deductions, "virtual" saved rent is taxed, tax on real estate capital gains).

@JonathanReez noting as a high earner in Germany: A good income can be of limited use if the housing prices are high enough. There's no way I'll be able to afford a house in a reasonable location with current prices with my income alone at a price similar to the rent that I pay, that'd take decades of saving or an equivalent mortgage, and that's a huge commitment. meriton's answer (other than fractional owning of apartments and sale taxes which don't apply in the same form here) covers my feelings very well.

@ave yeah, its a shame that accelerating construction and destroying zoning laws is not on the agenda of the (supposedly) socialist European government. Great time to be an evil capitalist with 100 properties rented out to the proletariat.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad especially since housing being a valid investment is diametrically opposed to (affordable) housing being a necessity

@JonathanReez This is just musin: : If renting is unattractive financially even for a high income earner as ave suggests, then return on capital for evil landlords [tm] should be poor in the housing market. And so NOT a great time to own 100 rented houses. Yes?

@RussellMcMahon if you bought these 100 houses between (say) 2008 and 2015 then your profit rates are absolutely amazing. Yes, if you bought them all right now you won’t do great but evil capitalists tend to come from old money.

@JonathanReez You're misinterpreting your linked numbers. The price-to-income ratio for each country defined as 100 as of 2015. Those figures are showing the change in housing prices relative to income (housing inflation), not an absolute comparison. And comparing to Canada doesn't show much; they're having a housing crisis now.

I think there are several factors:
Urbanization
In rural areas, where many people live in single-familiy homes, homeownership is quite high.
However, 74% of the Swiss population live in urban areas, where single family homes are rare, and most live in appartment buildings, which creates challenges for owning your home, especially since the legal instrument for owning part of a building (Stockwerkeigentum) was only introduced in the 1960s (which still lingers because ownership splits usually only occur when a building is new or totally renovated), and is rather cumbersome in practice. Specifically, while you own your appartment, you only own a share of the house, and everything that affects the house entire (everything from lawn care, utitilies, to the outward appearance of the building) is decided by a share holder meeting, and may, depending on the statutes of your association, even require unanimous consent. As such, a good relationship with your neighbors is recommended ...
Indeed, statistics show that the home ownership ratio is very location sensitive, ranging from 58% in the rural canton of Appenzell Innerrhoden down to 15% in the urban canton of Basel Stadt.
Real Estate Gains Tax
To reduce volatility of the housing market, all Swiss cantons collect Real Estate Gains Tax (Grundstückgewinnsteuer). Specifically, if you sell real estate at a higher price than you bought it at, part of the difference goes to the state, with the tax rate getting lower the longer you have owned the property. For instance, if you sell a property in the canton of Zürich after less than a year, you may have to pay up to 60% of the value gained as tax, but if you wait 20 years, you'd only have to pay up to 20% of the value gained.
That is, selling real estate can have rather severe tax implications, particularly if you haven't owned it for long. For those seeking to own their homes, this creates two challenges:

Since people tend to hold onto their real estate, comparatively few properties are available for sale, which makes it harder to find a suitable one.
Once you do found a suitable one you better hope the suitability does not change, either due to changes in your own circumstances (new job in a different location, marriage, divorce, more or fewer children than expected) or changes in the environment (those new neighbors who hate you with a passion).

In contrast, renting carries no such risks. If you don't like it, you can move without any tax implications. Also, in most areas, far more properties are available for rent than for purchase, so you have a greater selection.
As a consequence, most people opt to delay putting down roots until they are ready to start a family.
Availability of Capital?
The relative prosperity, growing population, and land use laws in Switzerland combine to cause rather high land prices, particularly in urban regions. As a consequence, a single-family home costs about 2 million there (in more rural regions, it's more like 1 million).
Swiss banks will loan you only 80% of the value of a home, the other 20% you must provide yourself. That is, you need 200k to 400k in assets to buy a single-family home. Even at Swiss salary levels, saving up that much money will likely take a decade, unless wealthy relatives give you a loan. For instance, OECD reports that it takes 11.3 years of average income to outright buy an average house. That is, an average couple setting aside 10% of their income will be able to afford the 20% downpayment for an average house in 11.3 years.
Indeed, home ownership ratio correlates strongly with household size (single person: 22%, couple with children: 46%, couple without children: 48%) and age (working age: 23%, working age and children: 41%, retirement age: 50%).
I could imagine that a nation with a lower population density, laxer zoning laws or less stringent requirements on downpayments, would make housing affordable earlier in life, and therefore allow a somewhat greater proportion of the population to own their home. However, this effect is likely minor compared to the other causes.

I think the answer above does not at all support the claim that the housing market in Switzerland is "dysfunctional". It is differently structured than in Anglo-American countries because of deliberate political choices: to encourage long-term renting, and to discourage treating residential property as an investment asset.

The mortgage interest deduction is absolutely an important thing in Switzerland, and encourages interest-only mortgages. Typically, you would pay off part of your mortgage, and keep the rest indefinitely. Conversely, you have to pay tax on the putative rent you are saving by living in a home you own (Eigenmietwert). I wish I knew enough to turn this into an answer.

and is rather cumbersome in practice. Specifically, while you own your appartment, you only own a share of the house --- this is very typical across Europe. For instance this is the same in France, Italy and Poland. I doubt that it would be different elsewhere because not having such a system would be very cumbersome (the only realistic alternative I can think of  is to have someone owning the building minus the flats but this doesn't sound good at all)

To buy a house, you must contribute at least 20% of the purchase price. Without this, it is impossible to buy an apartment or house, even if your income allows you to just pay the interest rate for the bank credit you took for buying that property. This is a rule applied by all banks and in all cantons (source). This limits the number of possible buyers, as a house often costs at least few millions.
Also, there are some laws that make renting attractive. The landlord cannot raise the price significantly just because the "market price" is now higher (they can a little bit, but this is very constrained). Many families benefit from old renting contracts with fixed prices below the today's market value that cannot be easily raised.

Aside from the other answers that are quite detailed, there is also an additional factor that comes to play:
Additional taxation
After purchasing a property in Switzerland, you will be taxed on it as if you were renting it to a third party. Meaning that, if you could rent out your property to someone else for CHF2,000 / month, the revenue taken into account in your wealth tax will then be increased by CHF2,000 * 12. Note that you can deduct some items from this sum such as the mortgage interest but in my opinion this is a major deterrent to purchasing a property for Swiss residents.

Specifically this refers to the Eigenmietwertsteuer, "Wer Wohneigentum besitzt und darin lebt, muss den sogenannten Eigenmietwert als fiktives Einkommen versteuern." = income, not wealth tax. This is based on the value of the house according to several indicators, differs per canton. This theoretical rent "income" will be added to your income and on that you indeed pay taxes. Rule of thumb: a third of the Eigenmietwert is payed in taxes, so for 45k/y Eigenmietwert, you'd pay 15k additional income tax.

It's not as much a deterrent as much as it is a remover of motivation to live in your own home. Because with this tax the end effect is net 0 compared to renting (where your landlord has factored that tax into your rent). It's just a stark difference to a lot of other nations where this is a direct incentive towards homeownership (because then you'd save the renting tax). So the deterrence is only presence in comparison to other nations (which, fair enough, is what OP is doing).

It's not a full answer but too answer-y for a comment:
Especially compared to the US, home ownership isn't as necessary for a decent, stable life.
Given the low renter protections in the US (and compared to Switzerland many other countries), it is paramount to own your home to have any sense in security or feeling of home about your living conditions.
In the Swiss market, thanks to culture and regulations (both empowering each other) this is not necessary. You can make your rented flat your home. Average rental terms (and expectations) are long, so it makes sense to invest into your place (even though technically it's not absolutely yours).
This is a stark contract to the US where - at least on social media - any minute change to the structure is countered with "but what about the landlord"

Can't landlords in Switzerland still kick you out if they want to move into the property themselves? So you never have security about the house you're living in.

@JonathanReez nobody ever said that you do. Yes there's still SOME risk. Just like your owned house could burn down, be hit by a meteor or taken through eminent domain. However, due to the Eigenmietwertsteuer (amongst other factors) the financial incentives are slim for your landlord and there are some protections for hardship cases. (including no alternatives being available)

You can easily get insurance for fires or meteor strikes. You get compensated if your house is taken away via eminent domain. You can’t take insurance on your landlord deciding to kick you out (AFAIK).

@JonathanReez how are those points relevant? Again: in Switzerland landlords do NOT have strong incentives to live in their own homes but rather to rent out. And insurances and compensation are the same as with a rented home: roughly net zero. If I park my money in an ETF and rent vs buy a house and cash out insurance the ETF+Rent way usually wins out anyway. So those arguments are wholly moot

They do have a strong incentive because of rent control laws: evicting a tenant, living in the house for a year and then re-renting it at a fair market price is a huge incentive.

@JonathanReez lol,  are you just completely and absurdly disregarding the insane (monetary and psycholocigally as well as time) costs of moving just to make a very weak point in an absurd hypothetical? I gave you an answer to your question, what is your problem?

@JonathanReez it almost seems like you jus "asked" that "question" to make a political point. This is the wrong website for that, go to r/landlords or whatever.

@JonathanReez That kind of behavior is very much illegal in, for instance, California. I would be quite surprised if it were legal in Switzerland. Anyway, it's really only relevant in inverse proportion to the number of properties a landlord owns. I would imagine that the  median Swiss landlord owns far more than 1 property.

A big factor is urbanization. It is no coincidence that many of the poorest countries — typically with a lower urbanization — in the world are on top of the Wikipedia list, and many of the richest ones — typically highly urbanized — at the bottom. City dwellers tend to live in condominiums which traditionally are rental properties. Farmers, by contrast, often own their property.
I find real estate prices and interest rates which are mentioned by others not very convincing because in an equilibrium market, rental prices must have adjust accordingly to provide a return of investment. If real estate is cheap, both ownership and renting will be cheaper as well.
Since Germany and Austria have comparatively little home ownership as well even relative to other highly urbanized countries, there may be a cultural reason.

The only two countries doing worse than Switzerland (as per Wiki) are Nigeria and UAE. Germany is 7% better. China is at 96% despite being extremely urbanized. Switzerland really is a big outlier by developed country standards.

@JonathanReez The google blurb claims 66% urbanization in china vs. 74% in Switzerland. But true, it is an outlier in Western Europe, just not that extreme compared to Germany and Austria. My urbanization argument was more aimed at an explanation why it is generally at the bottom of the list; it does not explain differences with similarly urbanized countries.
